# Getting document library location using C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, document-library

So I'm trying to get the location of a document library, but I've become stuck on how to proceed. This is what I've got so far:

```
    public string GetLibraryLocation()
    {
        var location = "";
        SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
        var siteString = siteCollection.ToString();
        //SPWebCollection collectionWebsites = siteCollection.AllWebs;

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteString))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPListCollection docLibCollection = web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);

                // Where to go from here..

            }
        }

        return location;
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is writing a method that can give me the location of the document library in the shape of an URL. With that URL, the plan is to obtain a folder residing in the library, which I'm then going to insert a file into. But I'm currently stuck on just obtaining the library URL. Any hints appreciated!

Comment: is it a list or document library. also why do you want to loop through all the document libraries to get one?

Comment: Good question, I probably don't want to do that actually. And it's a document library.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the absolute URL of the document library as

```
web.Url + "/" + docLib.RootFolder.Url
```

that is the same as:

```
string.Concat(web.Url, "/", docLib.RootFolder.Url)
```

or an alternative solution:

```
site.MakeFullUrl(docLib.RootFolder.Url)
```

In your case it would be (if you would lie to iterate over all of the doc. libraries):

```
SPListCollection docLibCollection = web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
foreach (SPList docLib in docLibCollection)
{
  var docLibUrl = string.Concat(web.Url, "/", docLib.RootFolder.Url);
  // or
  // var docLibUrl = site.MakeFullUrl(docLib.RootFolder.Url);
}
```

If you know the name of the doc. library:

```
SPList docLib = web.Lists[docLibName];
var docLibUrl = string.Concat(web.Url, "/", docLib.RootFolder.Url);
// or
// var docLibUrl = site.MakeFullUrl(docLib.RootFolder.Url);
```

See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/da4ff20b-786a-419b-8817-d1b75e17ff1c/how-to-get-absolute-url-for-list) for reference.

BTW, if your code runs in SharePoint context (`SPContext.Current` is not null), I don't see, why you create new `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects instead of using the ones available via the context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this context, how do I get to my document library, the one you refer to as `yourDocLib`? And you're right about the `SPContext`, I've changed that.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you out. No need to cycle through all document library lists in the web objects! if you know which one to pass then that's what you need.

```
    public void createLibraryLocation(string documentLibraryName, string fileToUpload)
    {
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);

                SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

                // Prepare to upload
                Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

                // Upload document
                SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

                // Commit 
                myLibrary.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

code was taken from here but amended slightly so you can call it passing two variables:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint

to use the method above just do the following:

```
createLibraryLocation("Documents", @"C:\mydocument.txt");
```

"documents" is the name of the document library and "mydocument.txt" is the file name located at "c" drive.

hope it helps.